# epigraph using \textit

Tags: horizontal-alignment, italic, mathpazo, epigraphs

I have created epigraph in my book using the latex command `\epigraph`. I would use `\textit` style but I got an epigraph that not follow the margin. when I use `\textit` it became squeezer

This is what I mean:

[image]

I would that epigraph should be big as the line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't provide a working example, but from your picture I'll hazard the guess that you're using Palatino or a similar font. Palatino's italic variant is narrower than the Roman one, and an epigraph that with the latter font seems to be justified reveals with the former font that it is, in fact, typeset raggedright. Solution: Redefine `\textflush` to `flushepinormal` (*without*  preceding backslash, as it is an environment).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{\textit{None is so great that he needs no help, and none is so small
    that he cannot give it}}{King Solomon}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yo! +1 for having a working crystal ball

Answer (score 3):

Please always provide a working example showing which packages are used (`\epigraph` is not a standard LaTeX command). However I would guess that you want

```
\epigraph{\itshape....}
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. I loaded a pic that show you the problem

Comment: You need to give us _some_ clues to allow us to help. Please post a complete small document using the minimum number of packages that shows that effect. Presumably it is unrelated to the italic font and the epigraph is that wide whichever font you use?

Comment: In this specific case, it *is* related to switching to italic -- seee my answer.